# Dynamic horizontal menu

Tags: dynamic, drop-down-menu

I am working on multilanguage project and I need help with top horizontal menu. Problem I must to solve is, that items (UL>LI) on top menu in every language is **various long**. In some language there is no problem in 1024px browser resolutions (no breaking line), in other there is not enough space in 1280px. 
So I search for script that convert horizontal menu dynamically to dropdown select list according your browser resolution. I found http://css-tricks.com/examples/ConvertMenuToDropdown/ but this convert whole inline UL>LI menu to dropdown select in exact browser size. And I look for script, that **doesnt change whole UL to dropdown, but only partly**. So in big browser resolution width you have all items inline, when smaller more LI change to dropdown - not all - but item by item. Something that checks and compare dynamically size of UL and browser resolution.
I have posted some samples of my problem on https://forum.jquery.com/topic/dynamic-horizontal-menu

Answer (score 0):

Try 'responsive' CSS by @media query .. It's simpler

Comment: Sorry, I did it this way previously. But as I mentioned, there are many languages used, so the name of one item in some language has just a few characters, in other much more. Therefore css for 1024 in first language looks empty, in other is breaking menu to two lines because of  not enough space.